# AltBeacon does not see eddystone device

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

Hi Everyone i have been working with beacons for some time using the Android APIs, i am able to detect all my beacons, one of which is an Eddystone set in URL, in fact the library `'com.neovisionaries:nvbluetooth:1.8'` recognises it as such. But when using the AltBeacon library no device is found, not even the Eddystone for which i set the parser

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {

protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkLocationPermission();
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    // Detect the main identifier (UID) frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    // Detect the telemetry (TLM) frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
    // Detect the URL frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));


    beaconManager.bind(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException ignored) {    }
}

private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("This app needs background location access");
                builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons in the background.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(dialog ->
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION));
                builder.show();
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                builder.setMessage("Since background location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons in the background.  Please go to Settings -> Applications -> Permissions and grant background location access to this app.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {});
                builder.show();
            }

        }
    } else {
        if (!this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        } else {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
            builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons.  Please go to Settings -> Applications -> Permissions and grant location access to this app.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {});
            builder.show();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is copied directly from the sample codes, the only new piece i added is the `checklocation` function that i added to fix a problem with the phone not giving me the permissions correctly when only using the manifest (as i discovered when i was using the original APIs)

also as extra information: my build file is set as follow: `minSdkVersion 24 targetSdkVersion 30`

Any idea why my code does not work?

Thanks

EDIT extra information from
**https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection-trouble.html**

1. NRF finds the beacon as Eddystone V3.0
2. The `Checkbluetooth` function does exactly that and i confirmed that it is getting the privileges correctly (based on my parallel app built with the android APIs)
3. Yes (see above)
4. Yes (see code above)
5. Yes
6. Yes
7. 
8. Not a samsung it's a BLU Grand M2

Comment: You should probably try this troubleshooting page, and update your question with the findings:  https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection-trouble.html  Also please augment your question to tell us which log messages (if any) you see when you run your program. How far does it get?

Comment: So, i opened the app this morning to update my question... and everything is working fine, apparently the solution was turning off and on again... i'm still confused to be honest. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the code works, turning the phone off and back on fixed it no idea why that is the case though